# The type or namespace name 'WinForms' does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reference, assembly-references

I was trying to biuld my project, when I got the following error:

*The type or namespace name 'WinForms' does not exist in the class or namespace 'Microsoft.Reporting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

I have already added this references:

using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

And I'm using Visual Studio 2010, with .Net framework 4.0.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you start it as a Windows Forms project? Have you added the assembly reference to your project?

Comment: This is the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/04/29/why-did-i-receive-the-error-the-type-or-namespace-lt-namespace-name-gt-does-not-exist-in-the-class-or-namespace-lt-parent-namespace-gt-are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference.aspx) I found when I pasted your error message to google. Need help in googling?

Comment: I have already added to the project, not only in the class.

Comment: Silly question, but I think the Microsoft.Reporting assemblies only show if either the SQL Server Reporting Services redistributable was installed, Reporting Services was selected when Visual Studio was installed, or a previously installed SQL Server Reporting Services report server exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you added the using its most probable that you don't have a reference to the Microsoft.Reporting dll. You need to add a reference to the Microsoft.Reporting dll in the project that is generating this error. I usually use the solution explorer in VS and right-click on the project -> Add Reference.

Do note that in the Add Reference dialog you generally have multiple sources available

P.S. I say the Microsoft.Reporting dll but because I assume that Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms is a namespace in said dll, but there could be a separate Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms dll